# Julia: Timer not working outside REPL

Tags: julia

Trying to use julia language as general purpose language.
I made a file called "main.jl" where I have this code:

http://pastie.org/9802792

For some reason I get printed "Create metronome" and "Start..." but no more prints.
If I copy paste that code into the Julia REPL it will work and I'll get the prints I've made.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm in Mac by the way.

Comment: It is important to put the relevant code directly in the question.

Comment: Even if the code is too long? That is the reason I "pastied" it.

Comment: If you can't reduce it to a smaller case that demonstrates the problem then just quote whyt you think is most relevant and also link to the full code.

Comment: ok then. in the future i'll take that in consideration though this wouldn't be easy in this case I think. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be simply that the program ends too quickly for you to see anything?  After adding

```
sleep(2)
```

to the end of your program, I find

```
dsm@notebook:~/coding$ julia tim.jl 
Create metronome...
Start...
Timed! the count is: 1
```

as expected.

Comment: Oh I see... Is there a way for the process not to be killed when it ends the code? Only with ^C

Comment: You could use `wait()` (see [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.wait) in the docs.)